# House Plant Identification and care

Tags: identification

I just bought this plant but it just said Tropical. I would like to know what it is and how to keep it looking so beautiful.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a [Yucca](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=Yucca%20household%20plant&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=yucca%20household%20plant&sc=0-21&cvid=09875087660843019C465747BA1CEC57&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&first=1&tsc=ImageHoverTitle). Does it have a trunk from which the two branches originates? It is very common for Yuccas as household plants.

From [this](https://www.gardenersworld.com/how-to/grow-plants/how-to-grow-yucca/) source:

> **How to grow yucca**
>
> Yuccas do best in bright light and can cope with some direct sunshine.
> Water only when the top few centimetres of soil are dry. Yuccas are
> tolerant of drought.

### Edit:

This [source](https://www.quora.com/What-would-be-one-main-difference-between-dracaenas-and-yucca-plants) offers advices on how to distinguish Yucca and Dracaenas:

> If you don't know if a plant is a yucca or dracaena, one easy way to
> determine is by seeing its leaf tip. A yucca, related to agaves, has
> similar leaf tip with that of agaves. The leaf tip is dryed and
> folded, becoming a stiff, thorn-like structure. If you brush the
> plant's leaves with the back of your hand, you can feel these leaf
> tips' sharpness against your skin. The older the plant, the harder
> these thorn-like leaf tips will be, and since the dead leaves don't
> fall down, these would make protective structure for its stem.

Answer (score 3):

This plant is possibly a Dracaena angustifolia or "Corn plant".

Answer (score 1):

I just found a Dracaena Rikki which looks exactly like my new plant

See: [Dracaena Rikki](http://mooreparkplantscapes.ca/dracaena-rikki-plant-of-the-month/)